# Error getting server's IP address using Python on CentOS

Tags: centos, fedora, python, sockets

I'm using Python's socket module to get the server's IP address

```
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
```

I get this error: `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Weird cause it works just fine on Fedora. Any ideas what's up?

**Edit:**
The problem was the IP address could not be resolved to the hostname since it was not in /etc/hosts. Works fine now.

Comment: What's the rest of your code look like? Is a service already using the port you are trying to open? Run `netstat -an | egrep 'Proto|LISTEN'` to check

Comment: No, a service isn't running on that port. I'm just trying to do the equivalent of `ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'` in Python without using subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the IP address could not be resolved to the hostname since it was not in /etc/hosts nor was it resolvable by DNS. Since I was testing on a virtual machine, `echo "X.X.X.X FQDN" >> /etc/hosts` did the trick.